# Stop a program from checking updates?

Tags: windows-7

I have a program that tries to update itself every time I go online. What is annoying is that the new version isn't compatible with the files I am using now so essentially it tries to break itself every time I open it.

How do I prevent it from going online and trying to update? I am using windows 7 x64.

Comment: There's no option in the program internally to stop checking for updates?

Comment: If my answer doesn't help, what program are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Firewall has the ability to do this out of the box.

Simply click the Start button and type `Firewall` and you should see `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` at the top. If you don't, then you can get to it through `Control Panel` > `Administrative Tools`.

Next, on the left hand side go down to `Outbound Rules` then on the right action bar click `New Rule` and basically select the `Program` option. Then after selecting the program, choose what you want to block, and then choose the `Block the Connection` option.

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm.

Comment: If the software is also installed in other machines in a home network for example (so it needs to be able to exchange data between the machines), is it possible to block it from checking for updates but not blocking it from working with other machines?

Answer (score 0):

Software like [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) can do this, there are (free?) alternatives but I forgot their names.

Another free option is to block the software in your firewall or to block the IP/Domain in your [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)).